# Scroll do tamanho da window

Tags: javascript, jquery, rolamento

Olá.
Bom, sou novo na comunidade então me desculpem se algo que eu escrever não ficar muito claro. Gostaria de saber como eu faço para dar um `scroll` do tamanho da tela do navegador, quero dividir o site em três, tipo um efeito "ancora" só que com o `scroll` do mouse.

Obrigado dês de já.

Comment: Não ficou claro pra mim o que você quer. Pode fazer uma imagem?

Comment: Então em vez do usuário rolar a página gradativamente como é normal,eu queria que quando ele rola-se  ele fosse para um ponto específico

Comment: @AfonsoJorge Usando uma função que detecta a ação "scrolling" você pode verificar se a altura esta em um range e este tem um ponto determinado na pagina para onde será definido o `scroll`.

Comment: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ Você pode tentar usar este plugin! Seria isso? Lembrando que seu site vai ter que se adaptar em resoluções menores

Answer (score 0):

Desenvolvi um exemplo, logo abaixo, que faz basicamente o que disse nos comentários da sua dúvida. Criei um [listener do evento scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/scroll) que verifica nos ranges, que são os [offsetTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) do `sections` da pagina, para saber em qual `section` a função [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo) deve posicionar o `scroll`.

```js
// Object usado para regra
var oScroll = {
  y: 0,
  sec1: document.getElementById('sec1').offsetTop,
  sec2: document.getElementById('sec2').offsetTop,
  sec3: document.getElementById('sec3').offsetTop,
  prevent: true
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  if(this.scrollY < oScroll.y) {
  // subindo
    if(this.scrollY > oScroll.sec1 && this.scrollY < oScroll.sec2) {
     this.scrollTo(0, oScroll.sec1);
    } else if(this.scrollY > oScroll.sec2 && this.scrollY < oScroll.sec3) {
     this.scrollTo(0, oScroll.sec2);
    } else if(this.scrollY > oScroll.sec3) {
     this.scrollTo(0, oScroll.sec3);
    }
  } else if(this.scrollY > oScroll.y) {
  // descendo
    if(this.scrollY > oScroll.sec1 && this.scrollY < oScroll.sec2 && oScroll.prevent) {
     this.scrollTo(0, oScroll.sec2);
    } else if(this.scrollY > oScroll.sec2 && this.scrollY < oScroll.sec3) {
     this.scrollTo(0, oScroll.sec3);
    }
  }
  oScroll.y = this.scrollY;
});
```

```css
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
.main {
  height: 1500px;
  margin: 100px 0;
}
.section {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="section" id="sec1">
    <h1>
      Section 1
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="sec2">
    <h1>
      Section 2
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="sec3">
    <h1>
      Section 3
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Veja o exemplo no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/qqLgdg1o/) se preferir.

Answer (score 0):

segue uma opção utilizando `CSS`, especificamente `transition` e `transform`.

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
var contents = document.querySelectorAll(".content");

var containerHeight = 100 * contents.length;
var contentHeight = 100 / contents.length;
var contentAtual = 1;
var atualizarContent = function (incremento) {
  contentAtual += incremento;
  deslocamento = (contentAtual - 1) * contentHeight;
  container.style.transform = "translate3d(0px, -" + deslocamento  + "%, 0px)";
}

container.style.height = containerHeight + "%";
[].forEach.call(contents, function (content, indice) {
  content.style.height = contentHeight + "%";
});

atualizarContent(0);
container.addEventListener("wheel", function (event) {
  if (event.deltaY > 0) { 
    if (contentAtual < contents.length) {
      atualizarContent(1);
    }
  } else {
    if (contentAtual > 1) {
      atualizarContent(-1);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
/* transform: translate3d(0px, -100%, 0px); */

html, body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;  
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#content1 {
  background-color: crimson;
}

#content2 {
  background-color: teal;
}

#content3 {
  background-color: steelblue;
}

#content4 {
  background-color: darkorange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="content1" class="content"></div>
  <div id="content2" class="content"></div>
  <div id="content3" class="content"></div>
  <div id="content4" class="content"></div>
</div>
```