# ScrollLeft JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#

Configurei o sistema, pra quando a tela for menor, formatar o grid, para ter barra de rolagem horizontal, está funcionando perfeitamente. Porém além da barra de rolagem, eu queria um button ou um link para que quando o usuário clicasse o grid ia se movendo para direita. Tentei dessa forma, porem não está dado certo:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
         function move() {
             document.getElementById('mobile').scrollLeft += 30;
         }
 </script>
```

Aqui chamo a função:

```
<input name="btnImprimir" type="button" onclick="move();" value="ScrollLeft" />
```

E coloquei meu GridView dentro da div mobile.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 414px) {
    .mobile {
        overflow-x: scroll;
        width: auto;
        height:300px;
    }
}
```

Porém quando clico no botão, não acontece nenhuma ação.

Answer (score 1):

Eu acredito que o problema não esteja no seu javaScript ou CSS, mas na forma como estruturou o seu HTML, neste caso à única ajuda que posso lhe dá é na forma de um exemplo funcional.

```js
var mover = document.getElementById("mover");
var painel = document.getElementById("painel");

mover.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  painel.scrollLeft += 100;
});
```

```css
html, body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.painel {
  overflow: auto;  
  height: 150px;
  background-color: teal;
}

.conteudo {
  width: 1500px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="painel" class="painel">
  <div class="conteudo">
  </div>
</div>
<input id="mover" type="button" value="Mover Scroll para a Direita" />
```

Comment: Tobias, fiz exatamente da forma que informou, colocando o código na minha página, porém ao clicar no button nada acontece. Ocorre a mesma coisa.

Comment: @marianac_costa fica difícil conseguir lhe ajudar, sem conseguir reproduzir o problema. Então edite a sua pergunta, criando um Snippet (Crtl + M) com as partes relevantes do seu código e que reproduza o problema.

Comment: Tobias, estou tentando adaptar esse código http://jsfiddle.net/josiahmccracken/pgeQR/4/ para o meu projeto.

Comment: Olha esta resposta, talvez lhe dê algum Insight [Scroll do tamanho da window](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116322/2363)

Comment: Tobias, se você pudesse me ajudar, eu joguei seu exemplo no JSFIddle e ele funciona, só meu código que não, copiei e colei exatamente, para o meu projeto, só que também nada acontece. Será que pode ser na declaração do JS ?